# Can't install ofono-phonesim or phonesim

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

OS: Lubuntu 20.04; Processor: Intel Core i3; RAM: 4 GB

I need to install `ofono-phonesim` or `phonesim` but I can't install either of these.

```
sudo apt install ofono-phonesim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: **Unable to locate package ofono-phonesim**
```

I see similar error with `phonesim`.

Dependencies: `libc6 libgcc1 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-script libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libstdc++6`

**Dependencies not getting installed**: `libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-script libqtcore4 libqtgui4`

Please either suggest a solution or some suitable workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `ofono-phonesim` was not included in Ubuntu 20.04, though it is available in the previous two LTS releases (18.04 and 16.04).

It appears that it was [removed from upstream Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ofono-phonesim) and [according to this answer from askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242450/when-will-add-ofono-phomesim-to-the-focal-repository-20-04) it will not likely be added back [until the official port to Qt5 is available](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=960941).

The linked askubuntu.com answer has a PPA that apparently works for installing that package, though I have not verified that claim or tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found same